# How to Scroll My ScrollView to the Bottom of Clicked View

Tags: android, eclipse, scroll, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` that has a vertical oriented `LinearLayout` containing some `LinearLayout`s inside it, that are items.

I have a event that when I click on one of those `LinearLayout`s(items) it expands and changes color and gets some details, but when I have a item that is at the bottom of the screen and I click it, it expands in the bottom of screen, so I can't see the details if I don't scroll down manually.

I want to: Automatically, my scrollview scrolls to where my item's (that I clicked now) bottom fits the bottom of the screen, so I can see the details properly without needing to scroll down or scroll up to see them.

How i can do that?

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutGeral"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orangeDark_overlay"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblRegistro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/orange_overlay"
            android:textSize="6pt" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.01"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text=">>" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNovos"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="Novos" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRec"
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="Rec." />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="9.94"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollContentSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/orange_overlay" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LayoutContentLeft"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnLetra"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.43"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:tag=""
                    android:text="A"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ScrollContentSearch"
            android:background="@color/orange_overlay" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LayoutContentRight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LayoutItem"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/linharegistro_par"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:minHeight="45dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:padding="5dp" >


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblRazaoCliente"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ADILSON ANTUNES CORREA"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblCodigoENomeCliente"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="274 - ADILSON - FLORIANÓPOLIS"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/LayoutItemEspecificacao"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@color/linharegistro_painel"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:weightSum="15" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEspecificoRazao"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="ADILSON ANTUNES CORREA"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/fonte_especificacao" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEspecificoCodigoENome"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="274-ADILSON-FLORIANOPOLIS"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/fonte_especificacao" 
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEspecificoEndereco"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Endereço: "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/fonte_especificacao" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEspecificoBairro"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Bairro: "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/fonte_especificacao" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEspecificoCidadeUF"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Cidade: "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/fonte_especificacao" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEspecificoComplemento"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Complemento: "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/fonte_especificacao" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEspecificoFoneContato"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Fone/Contato:"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/fonte_especificacao" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEspecificoEmail"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="e-mail: " 
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/fonte_especificacao" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEspecificoVendedores"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Vendedor: "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/fonte_especificacao" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/LayoutEspecificoButtonsTop"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnHistorico"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:enabled="true"
                                android:minWidth="100dp"
                                android:text="Histórico" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnPedido"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:enabled="true"
                                android:minWidth="100dp"
                                android:text="Pedido" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnAlterar"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:enabled="true"
                                android:minWidth="100dp"
                                android:text="Alterar" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/LayoutEspecificoButtonsBottom"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnVisita"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:enabled="true"
                                android:minWidth="100dp"
                                android:text="Visita" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnCobranca"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:enabled="true"
                                android:minWidth="100dp"
                                android:text="Cobranca" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnNFE"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:enabled="true"
                                android:minWidth="100dp"
                                android:text="NFE" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
        android:background="@color/orangeDark_overlay"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="3px" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnIncluir"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="Incluir" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCidades"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="Cidades" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRotas"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="Rotas" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any way you can alter you `ScrollView` to become a `ListView`? There is a built in `setSelection` for `ListView` that scrolls to a specified index of that `ListView`.

Comment: seriously? Yes, sure ! How i can do that ? :)

Comment: Can you post your xml for that file?

Comment: ok i did, see on the question, but a thing: i use clone to duplicate my LayoutItem and set them visible, so the items are generated dinamically.

Comment: I am assuming that the `ScrollView` in question is the `ScrollContent`?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that.

Comment: Then, could you help me ?

Comment: Follow these two tutorials: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-create-listview-in-xml-and-populate-items-using-arrayadapter/

and

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

This is what you want to do. Sorry I can't provide an answer using your code. It was hard for me to follow your xml because of how hardcoded it was.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks but i did read these links and this method will be too hard to implement on my code, unfortunately :/ But thanks for the luck, the help and the knowledge ! :)